# Does my SQL Server database use any Enterprise Edition only features?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, migration

I have a SQL Server 2008 database, up on an Enterprise Edition server. I am wondering if I can  move it over to a standard enterprise edition server. Is there any way for me to test the database to see if this type of move is possible, before attempting it?

Comment: Define "non-enterprise" - Standard Edition? Workgroup? Express?

Comment: Standard edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280724.aspx)

```
select * from sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features
```

This will not include though any application layer reliance on an EE feature, eg. query optimisations leveraging indexed views. But at least you will know whether the database can be attached safely to a SE instance (no compression, no partitioning, no TDE, no change capture).

Comment: That is restricted to SQL Server 2008. What about for 2005?

Comment: In 2005 only partitioning would make a database EE only and you can easily scan for partitoned tables in sys.partitions. See http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/SQL-Server-2008-Does-my-database-contain-Enterprise-only-features.aspx